# Spring @Configuration annotation with interfaces

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-java-config

We used `@Configuration` Spring annotation on an interface used as a root for other configurations (linked with the root via `@Import` annotation). Like this

```
@Configuration
@Import({
        DatabaseConfituration.class,
        JmsConfiguration.class,
        FlowConfiguration.class,
        SchedulerConfiguration.class
})
public interface RootConfiguration {
}
```

We specify in this way that `RootConfiguration` isn't a place for any bean definitions and the such approach worked well.

However, I've just realized that IntelliJ IDEA doesn't recognize `RootConfiguration` as a Sprint Java configuration. In [Configuration annotation JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) there is no any mentions about interfaces but only about classes.

So are there any prohibitions to use interfaces with `@Configuration` in Java configurations in Spring? Or is the issue actually IntelliJ IDEA problem?

Comment: I think if you make your interface looks like that, you can just make another annotation as `public @interface RootConfiguration`

Comment: @chenrui why do you think we need some new annotation? Existing one in good for our purpose.

Comment: I guess that is because I never see `@Configuration` is put onto a `interface` type?

Comment: @chenrui it's for using such simple context creation code `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RootConfiguration.class)`